# How to replace two or more underscore using python?

Tags: python, regex, replace

For machine learning porpuoses, I need to "clean" some text that I am extracting, so I've tried this:

```
texto = "sdf sdf s _ sfsf sdfs _________ sfsdf"
texto = texto.replace(r"_{2,}"," ")
print(texto)
```

But the result was not the expected:

```
sdf sdf s _ sfsf sdfs _________ sfsdf
```

I would like:

```
sdf sdf s _ sfsf sdfs  sfsdf
```

Comment: `str.replace(...)` does not include regular expressions, you'll need the `re` module.

Comment: In your attempt you seem to be replacing the underscore characters by a single space yet in the expected result you show what would be the result of replacing the underscores by an empty string because there appears to be two spaces between `sdfs` and `sfsdf`, which would be what would result using an empty string as the replacement. So why don't you just say in English what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are only concerned with the underscore character? If there are other repeated characters how do you want them handled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
import re
texto = "sdf sdf s _ sfsf sdfs _________ sfsdf"
rx = re.compile(r'_{2,}')

texto = rx.sub('', texto)
```

Which yields

```
sdf sdf s _ sfsf sdfs  sfsdf
```

If you want to replace the trailing space(s) as well, change the expression to

```
rx = re.compile(r'_{2,}\s*')
```

Then the output would be

```
sdf sdf s _ sfsf sdfs sfsdf
#                   ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply try to remove 3 consecutive underscores like this:

`texto = texto.replace(r"___","")`

Comment: What about 5, 8, 11, ... consecutive underscores then? You'd end up having two underscores here.

Comment: The OP wants to remove "two or more underscore.". Your solution removes 3, but not 2, 4, 5, 7, etc. (anything that is not a multiple of 3) correctly. A solution that uses a regular expression is required.

Comment: For any custom use case like where there is a sequence, you will have to write a Regex for specific string formatting